# error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `__nomain' with no type

Tags: c++

I have a simple C++ program here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main ()              //no return type for main. Yet program compiles and runs ok
{                    //when run by itself.
  cout << "hi";
}
```

But the program no longer compiles if I add a blank unit test in another file called `newsimpletest1.cpp`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

}
```

If I run it, it compiles and prints "hi" as expected.  But if I test the project I get an error:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `__nomain' with no type
```

When I add the return type 'int' to 'main', then it compiles and runs correctly.  I'm trying to figure out what this error is trying to tell me.

I'm using Windows XP compiling with Netbeans 7.1.2 using the default g++ compiler.

Comment: Error message should have been a bit more clearer. It should have said `... with no return type`.

Comment: Which operating system and compiler are you using? Your first code snippet is not standard C++ conforming. And the second code chunk is not a test of the first one! (they are totally unrelated).

Comment: Is the unit test in another file? The name main shall not be overloaded (C++ § 3.6.1:2). Furthermore, the main in your unit test does not have a return value. This is the error reflected by the message.

Comment: If main doesn't return `int`, then you have an ill-formed program and behavior is undefined. Anything can happen. Your program might crash, or it might run as though nothing were wrong at all.  Here is what happens when your main does not return int: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844915/what-happens-if-main-does-not-return-an-int-value

Comment: @EricLeschinski "Ill-formed" does not renders the program with undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says, that in a hosted environment, `main` should have a type.  Quote from C++ standard 3.6.1, paragraph 2

> An implementation shall not predefine the `main` function. This function
>   shall not be overloaded. It shall have a return type of type `int`, but
>   otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations
>   shall allow both — a function of () returning `int` and — a function of
>   (int, pointer to pointer to char) returning `int` as the type of `main`
>   (8.3.5).

Comment: In a freestanding environment (like e.g. a kernel) `main` does not even exist (and certainly has no particular meaning).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch In a freestanding envirionment, it is implementation defined whether there is a `main` or not, and what it looks like if there is.

Comment: Agreed, that is why I wrote "in a freestanding environment `main` has no particular meaning"

Comment: That's not an exact quote from the standard; it shows actual sample definitions, not descriptions like "a function of () returning `int`".

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: In a freestanding environment, `main` *may or may not* exist, and *may or may not* have some particular meaning. C++11 3.6.1: "It is implementation-defined whether a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a `main` function."