# Returing string from main function in c++

Tags: c++

Is there any way to return string from main function in c++? i am mentioning the sample program below

```
string main(int argv, char* argc[])
{
  .
  .
  return "sucess";
}
```

Comment: You may want to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Who will receive this string?

Comment: How exactly do you intend to use that string ?

Comment: Why not return 0 for success?

Comment: The irony of returning "sucess" (verbatim) is somehow... telling.

Comment: You can return `EXIT_SUCCESS`, so that you have the string "SUCCESS" in your *source code*... it looks good in presentations.

Comment: I am running the c++ binary from a shell script. i need to return the string to the shell script for further decision making.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844915/what-happens-if-main-does-not-return-an-int-value for the consequences...

Comment: @kayle Then print on cout... That's what it's for

Comment: @kayle The shell is getting the [exit status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) of the executed process, which can only be an integer. Use the [standard output](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_output) for that matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard says:

> **3.6.1 Main function [basic.start.main]**
>
> 2/ An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. **It shall have a return type of type int**, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations shall allow both
>
> - a function of () **returning int** and
> - a function of (int, pointer to pointer to char) **returning int**
>
> as the type of main. [...]

So no, you have to return an int.

From your comments on your post, you seem to want to simply output a string on the standard output, then you can do:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
    // No need for return 0; it is implicit in C++
}
```

---

As Kerrek SB said in the comments, the `return 0;` is implicit in C++ (standard *§ 3.6.1 /5*):

> [...] If control reaches the end of `main` without encountering a `return` statement, the effect is that of executing
>
> ```
> return 0;
> ```

Comment: If you read further down in that section, you'll see that `return 0` is redundant :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB You are right. I edited my post. Thank you for pointing this out ;)

Answer (score 4):

Nope, It's not standard compliant. You have to return an int in order to show to the caller how the program exited (good, with an error ?).

And why would you return a string ?

Comment: I am running the c++ binary from a shell script. i need to return the string to the shell script for further decision making.

Comment: For that, you might want to use the _output_ of the program, but it's also possible to convert the return value to some string in the script if you really want to.

Comment: @kayle If you want to use the output of the program as text in a shell, you'll have to capture it in the shell.  In bash, for example, invoke your program in `$(...)`.\

Answer (score 4):

No you can't, you must always return an `int`. Thinking more deeply, a string would be difficult for a shell program to deal with: when would the memory be released, what kind of string would be returned &c.)

However you can write to *standard output* or *standard error* using `std::cout` or `std::cerr`. That's the normal thing to do when you want a console application to output string-like data.

Typically, you then rely on your OS shell to direct the standard output of your program to the input of another one (unix uses the pipe `|` for that).

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean to **write to the standard output**:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    // ...

    std::puts("success");

}   // no "return", success is implicit in C++
```

That's one of the standard way for processes to communicate data, and many tools are geared for being used in this way.

Comment: Why use puts in a c++ program? Use the standard cout stream!

Comment: @KerrekSB: Why no? Mind you, I'm not imposing or anything, just curious to know the reason.

Comment: @legends2k: In this case, `std::puts` does precisely what I want, no more and no less; easy to read, and no hidden cost or default-constructed locales -- sometimes it feels nice to have something simple. I use iostreams when it suits, but I like to mix it up every so often.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Makes sense; there's no point in being a rigid fanatic of something without understanding what it really is/does.

Comment: @legends2k: I really wish I could like iostreams better. I use them of course for `getline` and such, but there are just so many ugly and icky parts about them (e.g. the monstrous verbosity if you're trying to write a hex dumper, or the poor performance when formatting numbers), that I haven't managed to embrace them wholly in my mind yet...

Comment: @legends2k: (Not to mention the wholly cryptic "facets" part of the iostreams library, which I have never, ever seen put to good use. I'd love to, and I'd love to believe it's well designed, but that revelation hasn't come to me yet...)

Comment: Interesting, this preference for functions which don't work (or at least prevent the use of functions which work later).

Comment: @KerrekSB Whether you use `std::cout` or `stdout`, both will always be fully constructed.  And I fail to see where `puts` is in anyway "clearer" than `std::cout <<`.  Just the opposite: it's yet another function you have to learn.  (What, for example, is the difference between `puts` and `fputs`?  And why do some functions take the `FILE*` as first argument, and others as last?)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't return string from main in c++, cause return value from main function is process return code (0 if success, not 0 if process failed). So OS is waiting proper signal of ending from your app.