# Return float value from C++ program not working

Tags: c++

Usually a `C++` program will be having `int main()`. I have a simple program to add two numbers and return the value as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    float num1 = 10.2;
    float num2 = 15.3
    float result = num1+num2;        
    return result;
}
```

I am getting the result returned as `25`. But thee actual result is `25.5`. I tried `float main()`. It is not allowd on `C++`. How can I return float value??

Comment: stop playing `float main()`, try float a normal function

Comment: What are you trying to return the `float` *to*?

Comment: You cannot return float from main. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844915/what-happens-if-main-does-not-return-an-int-value)

Comment: The value returned from main is the 'exit' code of the program which can be interpreted by e.g. an OS, where return code 0 usually means that the program exited normally. To "return" a float from a C++ program I would print it to e.g. the standard output stream and have the other program catch that.

Answer (score 3):

Return type of your function `main` is `int`. You can't return any other type from main() and there may not be any usage of such too. But any other function can return a float value.

```
#include <iostream>

float sum(float a, float b)
{
    return a+b;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    float num1 = 10.2;
    float num2 = 15.3;
    float result = sum(num1,num2);
    std::cout<< result;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yah you are right. But here the scenario is different. How to return float value?

Comment: @Banan corrected, copy paste of OP's code mislead me

Comment: @Steephan it also will return int value as result

Comment: @Santhucool yes main should return int. The intention of example to underline, for any other functions we can return float

Comment: @Steepahn so how can return float value?? I think he is calling this program from another file that is why he need to return float

Comment: @Santhucool we can't return float from main()