# C basic code not working as expected

Tags: c, getchar

I've just begun to learn C and I've got a problem with some basic code. according to the book i'm reading (C Programming Language) this code should accept user input and then output it. Instead im just getting the first letter of the input before the program closes

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;

    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }

}
```

Comment: you should use `int main`, because implicit-int is outdated. Also, return 0 at the end.

Comment: Try redirecting input so it is read from a file.   When input is echoed to the same device as output is written (e.g. a screen) you won't necessarily see everything you expect.

Comment: How *exactly* are you running this? The code looks correct, contrary to consensus below. This *will* line buffer stdout, so you won't see any output until you enter a cr/lf, but if you type "blah" and hit enter, you should see "blah" afterward.

Comment: I run it at https://ideone.com/qh3tak successfully. And yes WhozCraig is right, it is functionally the same code. Actually, the code is very much correct (it is an example from Kernighan & Ritchie). So the problem must be in the OP's IDE.

Comment: Are you on win OS?

Comment: @stackptr Since C99, return 0 is not necessary. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8677691/5399734

Comment: Is that the *exact* code you're running? Though it's a bit outdated (and invalid as of C99), if it compiles it should work correctly -- and it works fine for me. How exactly are you running it? What OS are you using?

Comment: The OP commented on a now-deleted answer that he's using codeblocks (that shouldn't make any difference). Code::Blocks runs on Linux, Windows, and MacOS, so that doesn't tell us much about the platform. The OP hasn't been seen on Stack Overflow in about 2½ weeks, so we shouldn't expect quick feedback.

Comment: could you post a sample output?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

Works correct.

Understand the basic concept of `getchar`:- `getchar` is a function in C programming language that reads a single character from the standard input stream `stdin`, regardless of what it is, and returns it to the program.

The main Problem must lie with the IDE.