# What's goes wrong with this code? What is runtime error?

Tags: c, uri

1. When I submit this code on URI Online judge, they show me runtime
   error. I have no idea about runtime error. Please someone can
   explain that

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    double x1, y1, x2, y2, result;
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2);

    result = sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1 , 2));

    printf("%.4lf\n", result);
}
```

Comment: Run it in a real environment on your computer to get a better error message.

Comment: Very hard to say. I cannot see that this would cause any runtime error as long as you give correct input. If you pass something else than 4 floats, well that would be trouble.

Comment: The format `%lf` specifies `double` when given to `scanf()` and `long double` when given to `printf()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Maybe in Microsoft land, but not in C standard land.

Comment: @IanAbbot MS dosn't even implement `long double` except as `double`.

Comment: Could you tell us which online judge exactly you're using? [Edit] the question and put all relevant information _into the question_

Comment: @WeatherVane That's true! `%lf` still requires a `double` in `printf()` though.

Comment: @IanAbbot I can't see anything else wrong with it. And `float` can be passed where `double` is expected in variadic functions due to type promotion

Comment: @Jabberwocky URI Online Judge Problem id  1015

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, `float` can be passed where `double` is expected in variadic functions, but `long double` cannot. (`%lf` behaves the same as `%f` in `printf()`.)

Comment: Perhaps with some negative values close to `0` the `pow()` function can return `-0` which then faults `sqrt()`. You should not use `pow()` for a simple square anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The site says "ANSI C" which is a commonly used misnomer for the **C89/C90 standard revision**... It is the obsolete deprecated version that no one should use anywhere - it does not accept for example `//` comment characters.

The thing is that the implicit `return 0` was added in C99. In C89 if `main` does not return a value, behaviour is undefined. It seems that the solution is not accepted if `main` does not explicitly `return 0`.
URI Online Judge uses GCC 4.8.5. GCC 4.8.5 defaults to gnu89 "dialect" and without explicit return from `main` [the exit code is completely random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677672/why-main-does-not-return-0-here). On the other hand calling it **Ansi C** is not appropriate either as it still does support things like `//` for comments.

Thus:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    double x1, y1, x2, y2, result;
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2);

    result = sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1 , 2));

    printf("%.4lf\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

works but

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    double x1, y1, x2, y2, result;
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2);

    result = sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1 , 2));

    printf("%.4lf\n", result);
    return 42;
}
```

gives "Runtime error".

---

Another thing C89 does not accept either is `%lf` to signify a *double* for **`printf`** - `l` is valid for *only*  `d`, `i` , `o`, `u`, `x`, and `X` conversion specifiers. Notably, `f`, is not listed! However either one works in URI, because glibc has for long supported C99.

Answer (score 0):

In some old C specification, values returned from the process will be indeterminate when returned from the function `main` without using `return` statement. (`0` will be returned in C99 or later).

Also there are online judge systems that treat being returned non-zero from the process as runtime error.

Add `return 0;` after the `printf` statement to avoid this error.

Also using `%lf` in `printf` is not allowed (invokes *undefined behavior*) in old C. Use `%f` (`%.4f` in this case) instead. (Using `%lf` for reading `double` in `scanf` is good)

Comment: Are you sure this is the reason?

Comment: @user253751 Do you have some other candidates of the reason?

Comment: @user253751 The [FAQ](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/faqs/about/judge) says that ANSI C is used on the system and this is one of "some old C specification".